# Pass form data using Serialize() throwing empty values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form when I click add button, it should pass the form data values to AJAX data. When I tried to use console.log the values are empty. I have tried both the `Serialize()` and `FormData()` methods. both showing empty values.

```html
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header clearfix ">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
     <i class="pg-close fs-14"></i>
   </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title p-b-5"><span class="semi-bold">Add Invoice Period</span></h4>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form role="form" id="invoiceForm" name="invoicePeriod" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <div class="form-group form-group-default">
            <label>Start Date</label>
            <input id="startDate" type="date" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <div class="form-group form-group-default">
            <label>End Date</label>
            <input id="endDate" type="date" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button id="add-app" type="button" class="pull-right btn btn-primary  btn-cons" onclick="addPeriod()">Add</button>
        <button type="button" class="pull-right btn btn-cons close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  function addPeriod() {
    var form = document.querySelector('form');
    //console.log($('form').serialize());
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    console.log(formData);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You cannot see FormData in a console.log as it is binary encoded. `serialize()` should be displayed fine. There are literally thousands of questions and tutorials about jQuery/AJAX if you take the time to search

Comment: _`serialize()` should be displayed fine_, @Rory the form fields missing name's that why the `serialize()` shows empty result...

Comment: Well spotted, although the OP appears to be asking a much too broad question (how do I send an AJAX request) not just about why he can't see anything in the log

Comment: I will edit my question then.. Thanks for the input..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form fields should have a name attribute if you want them to show in the `.serialize()` method result, like :

```
<input id="startDate" type="date" class="form-control" name="start_date">
<input id="endDate" type="date" class="form-control" name="end_date">
```

```js
function addPeriod() {
  var form = document.querySelector('form');
  console.log($('form').serialize());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form role="form" id="invoiceForm" name="invoicePeriod" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <div class="form-group form-group-default">
            <label>Start Date</label>
            <input id="startDate" type="date" class="form-control" name="start_date">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <div class="form-group form-group-default">
            <label>End Date</label>
            <input id="endDate" type="date" class="form-control" name="end_date">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button id="add-app" type="button" class="pull-right btn btn-primary  btn-cons" onclick="addPeriod()">Add</button>
        <button type="button" class="pull-right btn btn-cons close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.. it is working now.. My bad missed the name out of the fields.

Answer (score 1):

Your codes lacks of form action, input names and `Ajax` request.

```js
  function addPeriod() {
    //It could be better to get form by id because there might be multiple forms in the page
    var form = $('#invoiceForm');
    var formData = form.serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: form.attr('action'),//Or you can define the action endpoint manually
        data: formData,
        success: function( response ) {
          console.log( response );
        }
      });
      console.log(formData);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header clearfix ">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
     <i class="pg-close fs-14"></i>
   </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title p-b-5"><span class="semi-bold">Add Invoice Period</span></h4>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form role="form" id="invoiceForm" action="sample/sampleform" name="invoicePeriod" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <div class="form-group form-group-default">
            <label>Start Date</label>
            <input id="startDate" type="date" class="form-control" name="startDate">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <div class="form-group form-group-default">
            <label>End Date</label>
            <input id="endDate" type="date" class="form-control" name="endDate">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button id="add-app" type="button" class="pull-right btn btn-primary  btn-cons" onclick="addPeriod()">Add</button>
        <button type="button" class="pull-right btn btn-cons close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.. i just didn't post the Ajax request.. I will edit my question to serialize() is showing empty in console..